# laravel how to store 2 array into same row on DB

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5.1

I working on laravel 5.1. I was stuck on figuring how to store my 2 arrays input into the same row on DB. I only know how to store for one array.

```
$amount[] = $request->amount;
$receipt[] = $request->receipt;

foreach ($amount as $key => $value) {
  $reimbursement_item = ReimbursementItem::create([
     'user_id' => $user->id,
　　　'amount' => $value,
  ]);
}

DB structure and aspect result:
id  user_id  amount  receipt
--  -------  ------  --------------
1    32      40.00   /images/r1.jpg
2    24      60.00   /images/r2.jpg
```

Comment: You want to store two rows?

Comment: @AliN11 one row

Comment: Post current table data with expected data structure.

Comment: It's strange. How is it possible to store two different arrays in one row?

Comment: merge the two array and then store it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its better if you could update your request object structure like there should be one array and each index of array will have values for amount and receipt not individual arrays of amount and receipt

```
$data[] = $request->data;
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
  $reimbursement_item = ReimbursementItem::create([
     'user_id' => $user->id,
　　　'amount' => $value['amount'],
　　　'receipt' => $value['receipt']
  ]);
}
```

Another approach would be , If length of both arrays `$amount` and `$receipt` is same each time and the values are in correct order you can also update your data in single loop like

```
foreach ($amount as $key => $value) {
  $reimbursement_item = ReimbursementItem::create([
     'user_id' => $user->id,
　　　'amount' => $value,
      'receipt' => (isset($receipt[$key]))? $receipt[$key]: null
  ]);
}
```